# What is default access specifier in c# for class and constructor in c# with in different assemblies

Tags: c#

Plz also specify the difference between access specifiers and access modifiers in c# 
so if possible give me reference of msdn also

Comment: [access specifiers = access modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) and [What are the Default Access Modifiers in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521459/what-are-the-default-access-modifiers-in-c)

Comment: Why not simply search on MSDN if you know it exists?

Comment: "default access modifier in C#" in Google says it is `private`. Reading the MSDN shows that "Classes and structs that are declared directly within a namespace (in other words, that are not nested within other classes or structs) can be either public or internal. **Internal** is the default if no access modifier is specified."

Answer (score 0):

The default access modifiers for classes  is `internal` and their constructors is 'private'.

Comment: "for classes" is not quite right; for top-level classes it is `internal`; for nested classes it is `private`; both are "classes".

Answer (score 0):

Have a look @[Difference between access specifier and access modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5026254/1153464)

> In this context, you can think of access specifiers as protection
>   specifiers -- they specify where a variable can be accessed from. By
>   contrast, access modifiers are completely different; they specify how
>   variables should (or should not) be accessed; e.g. read-only,
>   volatile, etc.
>
> i.e., a variable can be public but read-only, or it can be private and
>   writable -- the access specifiers have nothing to do with the
>   modifiers.
>
> However, I'm a little surprised that the terminology is for C#, since
>   Microsoft actually calls public and private "access modifiers", and it
>   calls volatile and readonly just plain "modifiers".

Comment: this should totally just be the first line as a comment, IMO

Comment: @MarcGravell: I´m sry. You are right!