# Access Specifiers in MSDN

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I cant figure out the difference between an access modifier and an access specifier.I have read about modifiers in msdn and it sounds like specifier to me.Not sure about the difference in c# and msdn.

Comment: There is no difference. From [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx); You can use the following access modifiers to **specify** the accessibility of a type or member when you declare it. Access modifiers or access specifiers. They point the same things.

Comment: There is no difference, MSDN *somehow* uses access specifier for C++ and access modifier for C# *in documentation*, but they are same

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026220/difference-between-access-specifier-and-access-modifier

Comment: Thanks guys, I will take that there is no difference.